# Failed to download yiisoft/yii2-composer from dist:

Tags: php, yii2, composer-php

I am facing an issue now while composer install/update.It says

```
Failed to download yiisoft/yii2-composer from source:
  Failed to clone https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-composer.git via
  https, ssh protocols, aborting.
```

I am using `XAMPP` and cloned my repo from bitbucket using https.

**Composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced",
    "description": "Yii 2 Advanced Project Template",
    "keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "advanced", "project template"],
    "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
        "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
        "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
        "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": ">=2.0.6",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
        "2amigos/yii2-translateable-behavior": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-jui": "~2.0.0",
        "miloschuman/yii2-highcharts-widget": "5.0.*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widgets": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-helpers": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-editable": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-mpdf": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-grid": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-tabs-x": "*",
        "raoul2000/yii2-bootswatch-asset": "*",
        "rmrevin/yii2-fontawesome": "~2.12",
        "2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget": "~1.0",
        "uran1980/yii2-jquery-essential": "dev-master",
        "xj/yii2-bootbox-widget": "*",
        "vova07/yii2-imperavi-widget": "*",
        "creocoder/yii2-nested-sets": "0.9.*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-date-range": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-builder": "@dev",
        "wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform": "*",
        "phpoffice/phpexcel": "^1.8",
        "kartik-v/yii2-field-range": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-export": "@dev",
        "beaten-sect0r/yii2-db-manager": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2": "1.0.0",
        "drsdre/yii2-wizardwidget": "*",
        "schmunk42/yii2-giiant": "@dev"

    },
    "require-dev": {
        "codeception/codeception": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "*"
    },
    "config": {
        "fxp-asset": {
            "installer-paths": {
                "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
                "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
            }
        },
        "process-timeout": 1800
    },
    "repositories": [
       {
           "type": "composer",
           "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
       }
   ]
}
```

There were no issues when I updated my composer two months ago.
It is working in other Linux machines which my colleagues are using.
I tried some work around after searching like setting proxy for composer, `cacert.pem` downloaded from http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem and added path in `php.ini`. Extensions like `open_ssl.dll` and `php_curl`.dll are already enabled.

Anyone please help because I need a guidance on this.I think i miss something which i must do.

[please find the complete exception details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBdV2.png)

Answer (score 2):

Try to clean the composer cache. Maybe it will help you as your written example how I see is correct.

```
 $ composer clearcache
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply.I have cleared cache and try update again.Still it results the same exception while trying to download yiisoft/yii2-composer.

Comment: Thank you too sorry that this did not help you.
I will try to fiind other solution

Comment: thanks.I just tried removing fxp/composer-asset-plugin and tried to install it with "*",that also failed to download saying   -
 OpenSSL Error messages:error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify faile
d

Comment: See here is same issue 

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/2608

And Makarov mentioned this solution

http://mapopa.blogspot.ru/2009/10/git-insufficient-permission-for-adding.html
may be this help you

Comment: I have already gone through this link and i skipped because of the reason "error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database .git/objects".I think my issue is " fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-composer.git/': SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
".I skipped that because i can do git push,pull,status everything except composer failure

Comment: It was the antivirus enabled was making the issue.when i disabled it and run again it worked.Sorry that replied to it too late.